# iOS: UITextField's inputAccessoryView is not updated after rotating

Tags: ios, rotation, uitextfield, inputaccessoryview

I have written a custom `UITextField`, and added a button above the keyboard using the `inputAccessoryView`.

Here is the code:

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    var button: UIButton?

    var buttonContainer: UIView?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        redraw()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        redraw()
    }

    private func redraw() {
        button = UIButton()
        button?.setTitle("BUTTON TEST", for: .normal)
        button?.backgroundColor = .red
        let dividend: CGFloat = isPortraitOrientation ? 56 : 1
        let divisor: CGFloat = isPortraitOrientation ? 326 : 18
        let buttonHeight = ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 48) * dividend) / divisor
        button?.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 24, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 48, height: buttonHeight))
        buttonContainer = UIView()
        buttonContainer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: buttonHeight + 10)
        buttonContainer?.backgroundColor = .clear
        inputAccessoryView = buttonContainer!
        buttonContainer?.addSubview(button!)
    }

    func updateView() {
        redraw()
    }

}
```

And in the controller:

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: CustomTextField!

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { _ in
            self.textField.updateView()
        }
    }
}
```

Both `button` and `buttonContainer` are displayed correctly when I first rotate the screen, then begin editing the text field. But they are not correctly redrawn when rotating the phone.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems like you are not removing old instance of button when redrawing. You should either remove old `buttonContainer` before adding new one or change properties of existing `buttonContainer` on `redraw`

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using auto-layout?

Comment: @DonMag not really, I should probably do it instead, that's right.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr I solved this thanks to your answer, thank you!